# Add footer text to android overflow menu

Tags: android, android-menu

I want to add a footer text to the overflow menu in Android like Chrome Custom Tab which shows: Powered by Chrome technology in the footer of it's menu...
I don't know how to add that so I haven't tested anything since I don't know where to start...
Please help

Comment: What is "overflow menu"?

Comment: The three dots in the toolbar on the right side

Comment: Couldn't you just add another menu item with text "Powered by Chrome technology", which wouldn't do anything on click? It is possible to set clickable=false on menu items.

Comment: But I want it to have no effect on click like ripple ecc... And also it's size to be small in height